# how to retrieve values from Session object in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have mvc 3 application in which in session object I'm taking all values that is needed to me as parameter to execute stored procedure.

If the userAction is update then execute stored procedure.

```
public ActionResult Index(string userAction) 
{ 
   if(Session["Mappings"] != null)            
        ViewData["Message"] = "Mapping web grid"; 

    if (Session["PricingSecurities"] == null) 
        Session["PricingSecurities"] = objRepository.GetPricingSecurityID(); 
    if (Session["Cusips"] == null) 
        Session["Cusips"] = objRepository.GetCUSIP(); 

    SecurityMappingModel objModel = null; 
    mappings = (List<SecurityMappingModel>)Session["Mappings"]; 

    objModel = new SecurityMappingModel(); 


    if (userAction == "Update" ) 
    { 
        //please tell me how can i take values from Session[Mappings] and pass it to stored procedure? 
        //i'm trying this code
        //foreach (var item in Session)
        //{objModel.Cusips = (List<SelectListItem>)Session["Mappings"];
        //I did function import here (import my sp in model)using EF name            
        //ExecuteMappingsp.
        //dbContext.ExecuteMappingsp(need to pass parameter);
        //} //i know wrong code but how to fix this??
        // PLEASE HELP ME TO RETRIEVE SESSION VALUES
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    } 
    objModel.PricingSecirities = (List<SelectListItem>)Session["PricingSecurities"]; 
    objModel.Cusips = (List<SelectListItem>)Session["Cusips"]; 
    ViewBag.Mappings = mappings; 
    return View(objModel); 
}
```

How can I take values from Session[Mappings] and pass it to stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

Entity Framework Code First does not support stored procedure calls at the moment. The only way to do this, at the moment, is to use the `SqlCommand`.  (System.Data.SqlClient namespace)

#### Sample

```
// ....
if (userAction == "Update")
{
    // Create SqlCommand with your stored procedure name and sql connectionstring
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.StoredProcedureName", new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"));
    // set the command type to StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // Add Parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", Session[Mappings]);
    // execute the stored procedure
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Using Stored Procedures with a Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

### Update

I can't know your Model and if it is code first, database first or shema first because you don't provide that information. But maybe this helps

```
foreach (var item in (List<SelectListItem>)Session["Mappings"])
{
   dbContext.ExecuteMappingsp(PassInTheParametersYouNeedFromYourItem)
}
```

Comment: But i'm using Entity Framework ???
And problem is `Session["Mappings"]` is holding `object value` i mean it is more than one record currently having 3 records with 3 id , 3 cusip , 3cal so how to use it inside `FOREACH` to retirve and pass each as parameter

Comment: Entity Framework Code First does not support stored procedure calls at the moment. The only way to do this, at the moment, is to use the SqlCommand.

Comment: But i'm using Entity Framework ??? And problem is Session["Mappings"] is holding object value i mean it is more than one record currently having 3 records with 3 id , 3 cusip , 3cal so how to use it inside FOREACH to retirve and pass each as parameter

Comment: Entity Framework Code First does not support stored procedure calls at the moment. You can loop (foreach) to your object and add several parameters.

Comment: UPDATED CODE IN QUESTION PLEASE HELP ME TO RETRIEVE SESSION VALUES